# Reducing expression in textscan

Tags: matlab

On data like:

Student_ID  | Test1  | Test2  | Test3

1            91.5       89.2     77.3

2            88.0       67.8     91.0

3            76.3       78.1     92.5

4            96.4       81.2     84.6

if I use

```
fileID = fopen('grades.txt');
formatSpec = '%s';
N = 4;
C_text = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, N, 'delimiter', '|');
```

[then](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#btg0kes) Matlab will read the column headers using the format `'%s'` four times.

But how can I write in an easier way something like

`textscan(fileID, '%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %*f  %f %f %f %f %f %f %f', 'delimiter', '|');`
where I want to read the first seven floats, ignore the eighth and read the seven last floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be generating a format string dynamically instead of hard-coding it:

```
formatSpec = [repmat('%f', 1, 7), '%*f', repmat('%f', 1, 7)];
```

You can then pass this format string to `textscan`.

An alternative approach would be reading the rows with numbers as strings, and then converting them to numerical values using `str2num`, and discard the columns that you don't want, something like this:

```
C = textscan(fileID, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
vals = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num, C{:}, 'UniformOutput', false));
vals(:, 8) = [];
```

**P.S**
Did you know that `textscan` has a `HeaderLines` option to skip lines at the beginning of the file?

Comment: The problem is the file I am dealing with has no headers.

Comment: @bigTree then how would you call the first line in your file?

Comment: Actually the person who generated the file just sent me a version with no headers (but, indeed, in the original file, the first line has the headers)